# automating the merges for git integration branches?

Tags: git, branch, integration

According to http://gitster.livejournal.com/42247.html, branches can be either:

- "topic" branch = which contains all cohesive changes related to a single feature/bug-fix/experiment/etc
- "integration" branch = which picks/and chooses which topic branches to merge changes from.

I have topic branches `x`, `y`, and `z`

I have customers `A` and `B` which each want/paid-for a different set of features.

customer `A` wants `x` and `y`. That's easy enough:

```
git checkout A
git merge x y
```

and voila! I have what I needed. But how do I automate/record which topics ought to merge into A? This is what I did. In my config file I have:

```
[branch "A"]
    remote=.
    merge=refs/heads/x
    merge=refs/heads/y
```

and so now every time I want to update branch A, I simply:

```
git checkout A
git pull
```

and it automatically knows which branches to pull.

**Is this a good idea and/or bad idea?**

More specifically this is what I have in .git/config:

```
[branch "A.test"]
    remote=.
    merge=refs/heads/x
    merge=refs/heads/y
```

So that branch A (which is the production branch) never accidentally pulls any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that. Once x and y are merged into A, you'll have little else to merge from them in the future. Your work flow might need that though. Check out git-flow.

Comment: Thanks. For those checking it out later, the link he's talking about is: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . You can also Google "git-flow" to get many other webpages explaining and/or talking about it.